# Prevent/identify advanced brute force attack on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, brute-force

I'm running a WordPress build with WordFence & Image Capture and for several weeks WordFence has been alerting me to sporadic and consistent login attempts to the tune of roughly 10 - 20 a day. I put in the capture to combat this which seemed to slow it for a week a so and then has returned to previous frequency. The IP addresses switch after every two attempts so certain plugins/fixes are out of the question seemingly. My question is - is this a brute force attack and if so is it fairly advanced given that it seems to switch IPs, and how can I prevent it?

Many thanks for your input guys!

Comment: Easiest way is to rewrite the login url to something else as those are probably scripts hitting your login form. If they can't find it, they can't brute force it.

Comment: Yeah I think you're probably right. I'll integrate https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-login-url/ and watch this space..

Comment: doesn't WordFence handle login url rewrites as well?

Comment: Yeah it's one option to do this. It's updated so fingers crossed. I'm still curious as to how BWP ReCaptcha and WordFence hasn't managed to foil these attempts.